# How do I write only certain lines to a file in Python?

Tags: python, file

I have a file that looks like this(have to put in code box so it resembles file):

```
text
(starts with parentheses)
         tabbed info
text
(starts with parentheses)
         tabbed info

...repeat
```

I want to grab only "text" lines from the file(or every fourth line) and copy them to another file. This is the code I have, but it copies everything to the new file:

```
import sys

def process_file(filename):

    output_file = open("data.txt", 'w')

    input_file = open(filename, "r")
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
                if not line.startswith("(") or line.startswith(""):
                        output_file.write(line)        
    output_file.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
process_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: I think that you want `line = line.rstrip()` and `if not line.startswith('(', '\t'):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `line.startswith("")` always being true, `line.strip()` will remove the leading tab forcing the tabbed data to be written as well. change it to `line.rstrip()` and use `\t` to test for a tab.  That part of your code should look like:

```
line = line.rstrip()
if not line.startswith(('(', '\t')):
    #....
```

In response to your question in the comments:

```
#edited in response to comments in post
for i, line in input_file:
    if i % 4 == 0:
        output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: You can change the for part to be "for i, line in enumerate(input_file):".  That way you don't need to worry about initializing and separately updating i.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I will just add that I had to add output_file.write('\n') to get it to write every 4th line in a new line. Also, you might want to edit the writeline(line) part out of the second code in case someone else has this question and doesn't catch it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your script is copying every line is because `line.startswith("")` is True, no matter what `line` equals.

You might try using `isspace` to test if `line` begins with a space:

```
def process_file(filename):
    with open("data.txt", 'w') as output_file:
        with open(filename, "r") as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                line=line.rstrip()
                if not line.startswith("(") or line[:1].isspace():
                    output_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('data.txt','w') as of:
    of.write(''.join(textline
                     for textline in open(filename)
                     if textline[0] not in ' \t(')
             )
```

To write every fourth line use slice result[::4]

```
with open('data.txt','w') as of:
    of.write(''.join([textline
                     for textline in open(filename)
                     if textline[0] not in ' \t('][::4])
             )
```

I need not to rstrip the newlines as I use them with write.

Comment: The files need not be closed as they are not opened normally but used as generator. The garbage collector takes care of 'w' case on exit from function or program. Anyway, I corrected it to use with, which takes care of closing the output file also in case of error.

Comment: Nitpick: the files are opened completely normally. They're closed by the context manager (the `with` statement), which calls the `__exit__` method on the file object when the block of code exits. The file object is then garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if not line.startswith("(") and not line.startswith("\t"):
```

without doing line.strip() (this will strip the tabs)

Comment: he'll still need to use `line.rstrip()` to remove the trailing newline

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that (1) you are misusing boolean logic, and (2) every possible line starts with "".

First, the boolean logic:

The way the or operator works is that it returns True if either of its operands is True.  The operands are "not line.startswith('(')" and "line.startswith('')".  Note that the not only applies to one of the operands. If you want to apply it to the total result of the or expression, you will have to put the whole thing in parentheses.

The second issue is your use of the startswith() method with a zero-length strong as an argument.  This essentially says "match any string where the first zero characters are nothing. It matches any strong you could give it.

See other answers for what you should be doing here.

Comment: you're spot on with the boolean logic but you're way off on the second issue. look at the problem again

Comment: Oops.  You are correct.  Somehow, I had gotten it into my head that the OP was dealing with blank lines.  Looks like he found an answer that worked for him, but I'll delete the bit about blank lines.  Thanks.